# OpenGL Yuv411packed to rgb shader, cycled bad pixels

Tags: opengl, glsl, yuv

Y try to transform YUV411packed image from GiGE Vision camera with a shader.
YUV411packed pixel buffer is U1Y1Y2V1Y3Y4, so 4 pixels are in 6 bytes.
I upload buffer in GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, pixel format GL_RG8.

vertex shader is very simple:

```
#version 130

uniform vec2 texSize;
in  vec4 position;
in  vec2 texCoord;
out vec2  vTexCoord;


void main()
{
    vTexCoord = texCoord * texSize;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2DRect tex;
uniform int stride;
in      vec2 vTexCoord;
out     vec4 rgb;

/*
   R = 1.164(Y - 0.0625)                  + 1.596(V - 0.5) = (1.164 * Y)               + (1.596 * V) - 0.8827
   G = 1.164(Y - 0.0625) - 0.391(U - 0.5) - 0.813(V - 0.5) = (1.164 * Y) - (0.391 * U) - (0.813 * V) + 0.5173
   B = 1.164(Y - 0.0625) + 2.018(U - 0.5)                  = (1.164 * Y) + (2.018 * U) - 1.0937
*/
const   mat4 YUVtoRGB = mat4( 1.1640,  1.1640,  1.1640, 0.0,
                              0.0000, -0.3910,  2.0180, 0.0,
                              1.5960, -0.8130,  0.0000, 0.0,
                              -0.8827,  0.5173, -1.0937, 1.0);

vec2 fetch(vec2 coord)
{
    return texture2DRect(tex, coord).rg;
}

void main()
{
    int offsetX, quark;
    ivec2 iCoord = ivec2(floor(vTexCoord));


    offsetX = (iCoord.y * stride) + iCoord.x;

    quark = 3 * (offsetX / 4);

    int x = quark % stride;
    int y = quark / stride;
    vec2 srcTexCoord = vec2(x , y);

    vec4 yuv = vec4(0.5, fetch(srcTexCoord).r, fetch(srcTexCoord + vec2(1.0, 0.0)).g, 1.0);


    switch (offsetX % 4) {
    case 0:
        yuv.r = fetch(srcTexCoord).g;
        break;
    case 1:
        yuv.r = fetch(srcTexCoord + vec2(1.0, 0.0)).r;
        break;
    case 2:
        yuv.r = fetch(srcTexCoord + vec2(2.0, 0.0)).r;
        break;
    case 3:
        yuv.r = fetch(srcTexCoord + vec2(2.0, 0.0)).g;
        break;
    }

    rgb = clamp(YUVtoRGB * yuv, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The result Yuv411packed to RGB

[image: Yuv411packed to RGB]

As you can see, i have a cycle of bad pixels. I can't find where is my error. Help will be appreciated .

Comment: How does the geometry that you're drawing exactly look, what are the vertex- and tex-coords?

Comment: image and viewport are 400x400. vertex and tex coord are in QVector<float> coords {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem, i used an another approach.
Texture is now uploaded as GL_R8, but size is modified to (width*1.5, height).
Viewport is (width * hieght)

vertex shader

```
#version 130

uniform vec2 texSize;
in  vec4 position;
in  vec2 texCoord;
out vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    vTexCoord = texCoord * texSize;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2DRect tex;
in      vec2 vTexCoord;
out     vec4 rgb;

/*
   R = 1.164(Y - 0.0625)                  + 1.596(V - 0.5) = (1.164 * Y)               + (1.596 * V) - 0.8827
   G = 1.164(Y - 0.0625) - 0.391(U - 0.5) - 0.813(V - 0.5) = (1.164 * Y) - (0.391 * U) - (0.813 * V) + 0.5173
   B = 1.164(Y - 0.0625) + 2.018(U - 0.5)                  = (1.164 * Y) + (2.018 * U) - 1.0937
*/
const   mat4 YUVtoRGB = mat4( 1.1640,  1.1640,  1.1640, 0.0,
                              0.0000, -0.3910,  2.0180, 0.0,
                              1.5960, -0.8130,  0.0000, 0.0,
                             -0.8827,  0.5173, -1.0937, 1.0);

void main()
{
    float xcoord = floor(vTexCoord.x);
    float quarkIndex = mod(xcoord, 4.0);
    vec2 coord = vec2(0.5 + (6.0 * floor(xcoord / 4.0)), vTexCoord.y);
    vec4 yuv = (quarkIndex<1.0)?vec4(texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(1.0, 0.0)).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(3.0, 0.0)).r, 1.0)
              :(quarkIndex<2.0)?vec4(texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(2.0, 0.0)).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(3.0, 0.0)).r, 1.0)
              :(quarkIndex<3.0)?vec4(texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(4.0, 0.0)).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(3.0, 0.0)).r, 1.0)
                               :vec4(texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(5.0, 0.0)).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord).r, texture2DRect(tex, coord+vec2(3.0, 0.0)).r, 1.0);

    rgb = clamp(YUVtoRGB * yuv, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

YUV411 to RGB works fine now but i don't know why first approach doesn't work.